# SQL Server: Could not find type in the assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

Assume the assembly dll:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace CLRFunctions
{
    public class T
    {
        [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
        public static String NormalizeString(String s, String normalizationForm)
        {
            NormalizationForm form = NormalizationForm.FormC;

            if (String.Equals(f, "FormD", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                form = NormalizationForm.FormD;

            return s.Normalize(form);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Target the assembly to .NET 3.5 as SQL Server doesn't support .NET 4.0

Copy the assembly to a location, and "creating" the assembly works fine:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY CLRFunctions FROM 'c:\Program Files\My App\CLRFunctions.dll';
```

**Note:** And then enable CLR functions, otherwise they are [broken](https://serverfault.com/questions/155175/does-iis7-not-support-asp-net-by-default) [by](https://serverfault.com/questions/204008/connecting-to-sql-server-2008-through-an-adsl-router/208996#208996) [default](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/enable-Ad-Hoc-Distributed-Queries.aspx):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Created the user-defined function fails:

```
CREATE FUNCTION NormalizeString(@s nvarchar(max), @normalizationForm varchar(50)) 
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME CLRFunctions.T.NormalizeString
```

fails with error:

```
Msg 6505, Level 16, State 2, Procedure NormalizeString, Line 1
Could not find Type 'T' in assembly 'CLRFunctions'.
```

Why can SQL Server not find type `T` in assembly `CLRFunctions`?

[image]

**Note**: Why `T`? [Cause Microsoft did.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131043.aspx)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE FUNCTION NormalizeString(@s nvarchar(max), 
                                @normalizationForm nvarchar(50)) 
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME CLRFunctions.[CLRFunctions.T].NormalizeString
```

Comment: Great answer - this was causing me to scream obscenities at SSMS.

Comment: in vs 2010 the default template doesn't put namespace by default and hence my fully qualified class name was incorrect.  notation is: RegisteredAssemblyName.[FullyQualifiedClassName].FunctionName

Comment: For those reading this who are exhausted or aggravated from working with MSSQL; Notice inside the brackets... That is "the namespace" "dot" "the class name" or as @Lemblanc correctly calls it the "FullyQualifiedClassName"

Answer (score 4):

I just busted my skull on this in Visual Studio 2017, building a CLR in VB.
What I found out, when creating the procedure in SQL, THE EXTERNAL NAME is set as follows:

- `AssemblyName`.`[Assemblyname.ClassNameInVBProgram]`.`SubroutineNameInVBProgram`

And it is Case Sensitive.

Use `Create Assembly` in SQL to create the Sql Assembly

Use `Create Procedure` in SQL to create the CLR SP.

Comment: Works great _if_ you're creating the assembly _from a file_. But Azure SQL Database and Managed Instance do not allow creating assemblies from a file. You have to create it from a `varbinary`. Seems simple enough, except somehow it breaks the syntax of the `EXTERNAL NAME` clause. The exact same syntax that works from file in my on-prem SQL Server 2008 R2 fails when creating from `varbinary` in both the on-prem _and_ Managed Instance (SQL 2017) databases.