# SQL Server 2017 CLR Error: Could Not Find type in assembly

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I'm creating a CLR stored procedure in SQL Server 2017. I've done this many times in previous versions without any issue; however, we have recently updated to SQL Server 2017.

I'm aware of the security issues this upgrade presents, but I wanted to make sure I could deploy my CLR before I started messing with security. I created a database called `Test` and set `Trustworthy` to ON (bad I know -- temporary). I keep getting the following error:

> Could not find Type 'CLR_Get_API_Data.StoredProcedures' in assembly 'Get_API_Data'.

I found several articles e.g.: [SQL Server: Could not find type in the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823488/sql-server-could-not-find-type-in-the-assembly) that dealt with this error, but they built their code in a class and not a partial class of type `storedProcedures`.

This is my SQL Script to create the stored procedure:

```
USE Test 
GO

--Alter Database Test
--Set Trustworthy on

--EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security', 1;
--RECONFIGURE;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies asms 
           WHERE asms.name = N'Get_API_Data' AND is_user_defined = 1)
    DROP ASSEMBLY [Get_API_Data]
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY Get_API_Data
FROM 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CLR_Assemblies\Get_API_Data\Get_API_Data\bin\Debug\Get_API_Data.dll'
WITH Permission_Set = Safe --EXTERNAL_ACCESS 
GO

--Assembly Name,[SolutionName.StoredProcedures].Sub Name
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAPI]
AS EXTERNAL NAME Get_API_Data.[CLR_Get_AMS_API_Data.StoredProcedures].GetAPI
GO
```

My solution name is `CLR_Get_API_Data` and my project name is `Get_API_Data` and my method name is `GetAPI`. The following is my Visual Studio code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void GetAPI ()
    {
         // Stuff happens here
    }    //Ends Public Void Get
}    //Ends Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with using a partial class.

The `CLR_Get_AMS_API_Data` portion of `[CLR_Get_AMS_API_Data.StoredProcedures]` refers to a namespace name. Your code does not show that you are using a namespace. Remove the `CLR_Get_AMS_API_Data.` so that you are left with:

```sql
AS EXTERNAL NAME Get_API_Data.[StoredProcedures].GetAPI
```

---

For more info on properly / securely deploying SQLCLR projects in SQL Server 2017 and newer, please see my posts:

1. [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/) — more steps than Part 3, Solution 2 (below), but a good fit for existing projects as it requires almost no changes to the existing solution or even deployment process (and in fact, this is effectively the route that I went for my [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_59290525) project as all it did was add 3 simple steps to the beginning of the installation script)
2. [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 3: “CLR strict security” – Solution 2](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/)

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)